# app pool does not recycle automatically with Max used memory configured

Tags: iis, iis-6

In our environment, i set the Maximum used memory to 780, but the w3wp.exe does not recycle automatically when the memory reach 800, am i missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities I know of: IIS only checks once a minute, and the task manager number is not perfect. Take a look at private bytes on the process object in perfmon.